# Can't download images from Firebase Database by link or path

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi everyone i can't download images from my Database by link or by path. All links are correct and they are correct in app also. There is no any error in debugger and my code looks like documentation example.
I can't solve this issue for 2 days and nobody among my friends or guys from swift chats couldn't help me. Example of http link: ...firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F26.png?alt=media&token...

```
let urlText = modelArray[indexPath.row].imageURL
    print(urlText) //here is a print
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: urlText)
    let megabyte = Int64(1 * 1024 * 1024)
    ref.getData(maxSize: megabyte) { data, error in
        guard let imageData = data else { return } //1st breakpoint
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) //2nd break
        cell.itemImageView.image = image!
```

imageUrl was obtained from FirebaseStorage by copypaste. This link prints correct. I put 2 breakpoints to catch a problem and that is what i got from lldb:
`(lldb) expr error (Error?) $R2 = domain: "FIRStorageErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709538595 { _userInfo = 0x000060000078e2c0 }`

`(lldb) expr data (Data?) $R0 = nil` - data is nil! I couldn't find a solution of this error in internet.
Downloading images by path doesn't work too. Problem is the same. All other stuff from Database gets well.

All printed stuff:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F26.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F6.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F1.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F26.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F6.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F1.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F14.png?alt=media&token=xxxx https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/o/menu%2F30.png?alt=media&token=xxxx 2020-08-08 00:04:00.356154+0300 pFood[24374:1517416] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist 2020-08-08 00:04:00.650564+0300 pFood[24374:1517416] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60301000 started 2020-08-08 00:04:00.861852+0300 pFood[24374:1517416] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see xxxx) 2020-08-08 00:04:01.149822+0300 pFood[24374:1517416] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement 2020-08-08 00:04:02.406372+0300 pFood[24374:1517487] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800003] Registered an SDK that has already registered. Default flags will be overwritten. SDK name: app_measurement 2020-08-08 00:04:02.511475+0300 pFood[24374:1517497] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement 2020-08-08 00:04:10.454503+0300 pFood[24374:1517594] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled`

I tried code by @Jay and my console became look like `gs://pfood-5b1eb.appspot.com/menu/1.png. User does not have permission to access` its a firebase problem and we are going to fix it with team.

Sorry for my bad English. It is my first case. I actively check comments and answers. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Hi Emil, welcome! First of all, you should share your code by text, not by image. Apart from that, my wild guess is that the reference goes away since it's a local one. So, is the completion block being called right now?

Comment: "I can't" is a bit unclear. If you put a breakpoint on the first line in the callback `guard let imageData = data else { return }`, does it reach that point? If so, is there an `error`? If not, is there any `data`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen here is an lldb dialogue `(lldb) expr data
(Data?) $R0 = nil` and error content `(lldb) expr error
(Error?) $R2 = domain: "FIRStorageErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709538595 {
  _userInfo = 0x000060000078e2c0
}`

Comment: There's really not enough info in the question. First you should add a print statement so you can inspect the imageURL to ensure it's correct. Was the url obtained from `downloadUrlWithCompletion`? Does it start with `http:` or `gs:`? You may need to use `reference(withPath:` if not. Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay done edititng thanks for feedback

Comment: *This link prints correct.* can you please add to the question what it prints? Put xxxx where your url is for security - we don't want to see that.

Comment: @Jay added everything without links

Comment: Well, the link didn't print to console. See your line that says `print(urlText) //here is a print` - that should print the url to console - if you look at your question, it's not in the console. You may have an authentication/rules issue or the link you're attempting to use is not a valid link - we can't verify either with the data that's included in the question.

Comment: @Jay lol no all my 5 links printed correct and i didn't post them cause of your comment. I can send a screenshot to you

Comment: No. Just put the data in the question with your url path blocked out for security.

Comment: @Jay okay here is full stuff without tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer but may lead to one.

Part of troubleshooting is catching errors returned from the server when they occur and providing that info to you (the developer) or the the end user.

The code in the question totally ignores any errors returned from the server so if there is one, we don't know what it is.

Try changing your code to catch and handle errors - this will give you more information about the current issue:

```
let urlText = modelArray[indexPath.row].imageURL
let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: urlText)
let megabyte = Int64(1 * 1024 * 1024)
ref.getData(maxSize: megabyte) { maybeData, maybeError in
    if let err = maybeError {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    
    guard let imageData = maybeData else {
        print("data was nil, file not found")
        return
    }
    
    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        cell.itemImageView.image = image
    } else {
        print("imageData was not valid")
    }
}
```

It's looking like an authentication or rules issue so please update the question when more info is available based on my code change.

Comment: It helped us to understand problem. It is in Firebase itself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem really was not about code. We just need switch permission access in Firebase Storage. It was a stupid problem lol. Thank you for feedback!